How to set the Invoice Tax percentage?
How to set the invoice sales tax percentage through PHP code? I set the Tax Name with code but could not find any solution to set this percentage. I could not find any methods which set the percentage as well.
When querying the invoice record, the sales tax amount appears in the code below. However, I couldn’t find any field in this package where I can set the tax percentage.
<SalesTaxPercentage>0.00</SalesTaxPercentage>

Does anyone know how to set this value?

$quickbooks_invoice = new \QuickBooks_QBXML_Object_Invoice();
$quickbooks_invoice_line->setTaxable();

$quickbooks_invoice->setSalesTaxItemFullName($sales_tax_item_name); //NJ Sales Tax

//HOW TO SET PERCENTAGE??
$quickbooks_invoice->setRatePercent(5);
OR
$quickbooks_invoice->setsalesTaxPercentage(5);

